# Generalizing a non linear model in pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I would like to know if there is a way to take a non linear model in pyomo format from the user, and load it into the pyomo optimization code. I'm asking this since i'm dealing with non linear models, and need to develop a generic code to implement a particular type of optimization using these models. Kindly help me out.
Thank you

Comment: Hi Anuja, could you clarify what you mean by "load it into the pyomo optimization code"? If the NLP is already in a Pyomo format, that ought to mean that it is loaded in already?

Comment: Hi Qi. I'm sorry for the incorrect language. I would like to know, how to declare constraints in pyomo after taking the model equations as input from the user. Since user input (taken using the input() function in python) has a string format, it cannot be directly used to declare the constraints. Kindly help me out with it.

Comment: This would require you to write a string parser, there is no automatic way to do this in Pyomo. Once you had a string parser you could easily generate Pyomo constraints programmatically.